# CentOS 7 Blank Screen On Boot

Tags: centos7, drivers

CentOS 7 boots, shows the grey 7 background with a spinner icon, then the screen goes blank, monitor goes to sleep. I can still log in via SSH. Everything seems to be in order *except* monitor issues.

This is recent. I'm sure I ran a general update recently, but I didn't specifically install any new video drivers.

Thoughts on getting things back in order?

```
== BEGIN uname -rmi ==
3.10.0-327.3.1.el7.x86_64 x86_64 x86_64
== END   uname -rmi ==

== BEGIN rpm -qa \*-release\* ==
centos-release-7-2.1511.el7.centos.2.10.x86_64
== END   rpm -qa \*-release\* ==

== BEGIN cat /etc/redhat-release ==
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core) 
== END   cat /etc/redhat-release ==

== BEGIN getenforce ==
Permissive
== END   getenforce ==

== BEGIN free -m ==
          total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7710         363        6791           9         554        7081
Swap:          7935           0        7935
== END   free -m ==

== BEGIN rpm -qa kernel\* | sort ==
kernel-3.10.0-229.11.1.el7.x86_64
kernel-3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64
kernel-3.10.0-327.3.1.el7.x86_64
kernel-devel-3.10.0-229.11.1.el7.x86_64
kernel-devel-3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64
kernel-devel-3.10.0-327.3.1.el7.x86_64
kernel-headers-3.10.0-327.3.1.el7.x86_64
kernel-tools-3.10.0-327.3.1.el7.x86_64
kernel-tools-libs-3.10.0-327.3.1.el7.x86_64
== END   rpm -qa kernel\* | sort ==

== BEGIN lspci -nn ==
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 DMI2 [8086:2f00] (rev 02)
00:02.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 PCI Express Root Port 2 [8086:2f04] (rev 02)
00:03.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 PCI Express Root Port 3 [8086:2f08] (rev 02)
00:05.0 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Address Map, VTd_Misc, System Management [8086:2f28] (rev 02)
00:05.1 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Hot Plug [8086:2f29] (rev 02)
00:05.2 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 RAS, Control Status and Global Errors [8086:2f2a] (rev 02)
00:05.4 PIC [0800]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 I/O APIC [8086:2f2c] (rev 02)
00:11.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset SPSR [8086:8d7c] (rev 05)
00:11.4 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset sSATA Controller [AHCI mode] [8086:8d62] (rev 05)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset MEI Controller #1 [8086:8d3a] (rev 05)
00:16.1 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset MEI Controller #2 [8086:8d3b] (rev 05)
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:8d2d] (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset PCI Express Root Port #1 [8086:8d10] (rev d5)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset PCI Express Root Port #2 [8086:8d12] (rev d5)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset PCI Express Root Port #3 [8086:8d14] (rev d5)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset PCI Express Root Port #5 [8086:8d18] (rev d5)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:8d26] (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset LPC Controller [8086:8d44] (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset 6-Port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [8086:8d02] (rev 05)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5720 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:165f]
01:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5720 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:165f]
03:00.0 RAID bus controller [0104]: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic MegaRAID SAS-3 3108 [Invader] [1000:005d] (rev 02)
05:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Renesas Technology Corp. Device [1912:001d]
06:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Renesas Technology Corp. Device [1912:001d]
07:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Renesas Technology Corp. Device [1912:001a]
08:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Matrox Electronics Systems Ltd. G200eR2 [102b:0534] (rev 01)
ff:0b.0 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 R3 QPI Link 0 & 1 Monitoring [8086:2f81] (rev 02)
ff:0b.1 Performance counters [1101]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 R3 QPI Link 0 & 1 Monitoring [8086:2f36] (rev 02)
ff:0b.2 Performance counters [1101]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 R3 QPI Link 0 & 1 Monitoring [8086:2f37] (rev 02)
ff:0c.0 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Unicast Registers [8086:2fe0] (rev 02)
ff:0c.1 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Unicast Registers [8086:2fe1] (rev 02)
ff:0c.2 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Unicast Registers [8086:2fe2] (rev 02)
ff:0c.3 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Unicast Registers [8086:2fe3] (rev 02)
ff:0c.4 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Unicast Registers [8086:2fe4] (rev 02)
ff:0c.5 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Unicast Registers [8086:2fe5] (rev 02)
ff:0f.0 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Buffered Ring Agent [8086:2ff8] (rev 02)
ff:0f.1 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Buffered Ring Agent [8086:2ff9] (rev 02)
ff:0f.4 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 System Address Decoder & Broadcast Registers [8086:2ffc] (rev 02)
ff:0f.5 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 System Address Decoder & Broadcast Registers [8086:2ffd] (rev 02)
ff:0f.6 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 System Address Decoder & Broadcast Registers [8086:2ffe] (rev 02)
ff:10.0 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 PCIe Ring Interface [8086:2f1d] (rev 02)
ff:10.1 Performance counters [1101]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 PCIe Ring Interface [8086:2f34] (rev 02)
ff:10.5 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Scratchpad & Semaphore Registers [8086:2f1e] (rev 02)
ff:10.6 Performance counters [1101]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Scratchpad & Semaphore Registers [8086:2f7d] (rev 02)
ff:10.7 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Scratchpad & Semaphore Registers [8086:2f1f] (rev 02)
ff:12.0 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Home Agent 0 [8086:2fa0] (rev 02)
ff:12.1 Performance counters [1101]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Home Agent 0 [8086:2f30] (rev 02)
ff:12.2 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Home Agent 0 Debug [8086:2f70] (rev 02)
ff:13.0 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Target Address, Thermal & RAS Registers [8086... (rev 02)
ff:13.1 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Target Address, Thermal & RAS Registers [8086... (rev 02)
ff:13.2 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel Target Address Decoder [8086:2faa] (rev 02)
ff:13.3 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel Target Address Decoder [8086:2fab] (rev 02)
ff:13.4 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel Target Address Decoder [8086:2fac] (rev 02)
ff:13.5 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel Target Address Decoder [8086:2fad] (rev 02)
ff:13.6 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 DDRIO Channel 0/1 Broadcast [8086:2fae] (rev 02)
ff:13.7 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 DDRIO Global Broadcast [8086:2faf] (rev 02)
ff:14.0 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel 0 Thermal Control [8086:2fb0] (rev 02)
ff:14.1 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel 1 Thermal Control [8086:2fb1] (rev 02)
ff:14.2 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel 0 ERROR Registers [8086:2fb2] (rev 02)
ff:14.3 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel 1 ERROR Registers [8086:2fb3] (rev 02)
ff:14.4 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 DDRIO (VMSE) 0 & 1 [8086:2fbc] (rev 02)
ff:14.5 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 DDRIO (VMSE) 0 & 1 [8086:2fbd] (rev 02)
ff:14.6 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 DDRIO (VMSE) 0 & 1 [8086:2fbe] (rev 02)
ff:14.7 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 DDRIO (VMSE) 0 & 1 [8086:2fbf] (rev 02)
ff:15.0 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel 2 Thermal Control [8086:2fb4] (rev 02)
ff:15.1 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel 3 Thermal Control [8086:2fb5] (rev 02)
ff:15.2 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel 2 ERROR Registers [8086:2fb6] (rev 02)
ff:15.3 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel 3 ERROR Registers [8086:2fb7] (rev 02)
ff:16.0 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 1 Target Address, Thermal & RAS Registers [8086... (rev 02)
ff:16.6 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 DDRIO Channel 2/3 Broadcast [8086:2f6e] (rev 02)
ff:16.7 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 DDRIO Global Broadcast [8086:2f6f] (rev 02)
ff:17.0 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 1 Channel 0 Thermal Control [8086:2fd0] (rev 02)
ff:17.4 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 DDRIO (VMSE) 2 & 3 [8086:2fb8] (rev 02)
ff:17.5 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 DDRIO (VMSE) 2 & 3 [8086:2fb9] (rev 02)
ff:17.6 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 DDRIO (VMSE) 2 & 3 [8086:2fba] (rev 02)
ff:17.7 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 DDRIO (VMSE) 2 & 3 [8086:2fbb] (rev 02)
ff:1e.0 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Power Control Unit [8086:2f98] (rev 02)
ff:1e.1 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Power Control Unit [8086:2f99] (rev 02)
ff:1e.2 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Power Control Unit [8086:2f9a] (rev 02)
ff:1e.3 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Power Control Unit [8086:2fc0] (rev 02)
ff:1e.4 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 Power Control Unit [8086:2f9c] (rev 02)
ff:1f.0 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 VCU [8086:2f88] (rev 02)
ff:1f.2 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 VCU [8086:2f8a] (rev 02)
== END   lspci -nn ==

== BEGIN lspci -vnn | grep VGA - A 12 ==
08:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Matrox Electronics Systems Ltd. G200eR2 [102b:0534] (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:063b]
Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
Memory at 90000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=16M]
Memory at 91800000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Memory at 91000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8M]
Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: mgag200

ff:0b.0 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 R3 QPI Link 0 & 1 Monitoring [8086:2f81] (rev 02)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v3/Xeon E5 v3/Core i7 R3 QPI Link 0 & 1 Monitoring [8086:2f81]
Flags: fast devsel
== END   lspci -vnn | grep VGA - A 12 ==

== BEGIN lsusb ==
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:800a Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8002 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:0939 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 413c:a001 Dell Computer Corp. Hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04f2:0833 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
== END   lsusb ==

== BEGIN rpm -qa kmod\* kmdl\* ==
kmod-20-5.el7.x86_64
kmod-libs-20-5.el7.x86_64
== END   rpm -qa kmod\* kmdl\* ==
```

/var/log/Xorg.0.log

```
[    25.959] 
X.Org X Server 1.17.2
Release Date: 2015-06-16
[    25.959] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    25.959] Build Operating System:  2.6.32-220.17.1.el6.x86_64 
[    25.959] Current Operating System: Linux munin.nsp 3.10.0-327.3.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Dec 9 14:09:15 UTC 2015 x86_64
[    25.960] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.10.0-327.3.1.el7.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/centos-root ro rd.lvm.lv=centos/root rd.lvm.lv=centos/swap crashkernel=auto rhgb quiet LANG=en_US.UTF-8 systemd.debug
[    25.960] Build Date: 20 November 2015  02:44:25PM
[    25.960] Build ID: xorg-x11-server 1.17.2-10.el7 
[    25.960] Current version of pixman: 0.32.6
[    25.960]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    25.960] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    25.960] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Mon Dec 28 16:10:43 2015
[    25.983] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[    25.983] (==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    25.983] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    26.059] Parse error on line 1 of section InputClass in file /etc/X11/xorg.conf
    "ection" is not a valid keyword in this section.
[    26.059] (EE) Problem parsing the config file
[    26.059] (EE) Error parsing the config file
[    26.059] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[    26.059] (EE) no screens found(EE) 
[    26.059] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[    26.059] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[    26.059] (EE) 
[    26.060] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

Comment: You need to look at `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`.

Comment: OMG. "ection" instead of "Section"
That's so dumb. I have no idea how I did that. Thanks for the help. That solved it, for sure.

Answer (score -1):

Answer via [Michael Hampton](https://serverfault.com/users/126632/michael-hampton).

Syntax error in /etc/X11/xorg.conf

:)

Comment: Please post the entire answer in the answer.